# PHP 5.x vs 7.x - object properties using variables behaving differently

Tags: php, variables

Imagine the following situation in PHP 5.x, where i have a class. In this class i have two variables being used:

```
$this->my_row;  # contains a row from a mysqli query, object style
$field['name']; # contains (just) the name of the field in the row i want to retrieve
```

Let's assume the $this->my_row contains a row with 2 fields (and their values):

```
exam='bio'
grade='A'
```

Also let's assume:

```
$field['name']='exam';
```

Then if I use this code:

```
$value = $this->my_row->$field['name']
```

`$value` would evaluate to: 'bio'

This worked like a charm for years. NOW, I started using PHP 7 (better late then never). Since then, the code no longer works (the result is always empty). To achieve the old result, I need to have a step in between:

```
$tmp_name=$field['name'];
$this->my_row->$tmp_name;
```

Any idea why? My guess is that the ['name'] is the culprit. maybe the way PHP 7 evaluates the order of the statement?

Comment: I assume that the typos in your shown code is only here in your question and not in the actual code?

Comment: no answer sorry but `$this->my_row->{$field['name']}` can be used too

Comment: Epodax, What typos are you referring to? Ands Scuzzy, I should have thought of that, I use that in strings sometimes, but never in the statements themself. That is an easy soluition. But as you say, I still am curious why the behaviour changed

Comment: `$this->my_row->$tmp_name';` <- You have a rogue `'` just before the ending `;` and both lines in your second block of code is missing their ending `;` for example.

Comment: @PaulCrovella : this is exactly whsat I was looking for. As I suspected, the order of evaluation is different in PHP7, apparently. Thank you! (I cant mark as soluiton, because you did it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [explained in the PHP 5.6 to 7.0 migration guide](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling).

In summary, there's 2 reasons for this:

1. Ambiguity; `my_row->$field['name']` could be interpreted as either:

   - `{my_row->$field}['name']`
   - `my_row->{$field['name']}`
2. Consistency, as PHP 5 sometimes evaluates such ambuguous statements as left-to-right, and other times as right-to-left, depending on the case. That's hard to follow and makes for easy mistakes (or forces you to always put parentheses in order to be sure).

   PHP 7 simply introduces a reliable left-to-right rule.

Comment: Shouldnt it be curly brackets? Other then that, this is what i was looking for.